# tcp packet/receive and compared numbers, optimization learning question

Tags: bash

I use this code on embedded device to receive chapter number, this is number after sign "/" if is more than 01, execute script:

```
  echo -n "REMOTE QCH" | /tmp/nc 0.0.0.0 48360 > /tmp/QCH
  sleep 1s
  a=$(cat /tmp/QCH | grep -o '[^/":]\+$' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*')
  if [ "$a" -gt "01" ]; then  
    echo "action"
  fi
```

This code send tcp packet/receive and save to file /tmp/QCH, It can give you numbers 01/12, 04/18...

```
echo -n "REMOTE QCH" | /tmp/nc 0.0.0.0 48360 > /tmp/QCH
```

**Everything works fine, I wrote the code myself, but is it well optimized? maybe can be faster or better?**

Greetings

Comment: `Everything works fine` if it ain't broke don't fix it. No, seriously, if performance is good enough, why bother changing it? This sounds more like a learning question than an actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not optimized.  bash in general is slower than a compiled language such as C.  Pipes also take up a lot a resources; most, if not all could be removed.  grep and regular expressions can use a lot of resources; replacing these with exact string matches, if possible, is almost always more optimized and often possible (not suer in this case). Not storing variables, also might optimize memory usage (trivial).

Another issue, regarding correctness, is that /tmp/QCH might change in 1 second, which would break the cat